# jquery mobile prevent submit

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, submit, preventdefault

I had to use .`live()` because `.on()` or `.submit()` wouldn't fire

```
$('.submit_coment').live('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('Submit Comment');
    return false;
});
```

The thing is that now the console.log is fired but the form is submited naturally (page refreshed)

Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery mobile doesn't use standard requests, everything is done via AJAX handler which it attaches to every form. To prevent this you need to put the `data-ajax="false"` attribute on the `form` element. This will then allow you to hook to the `submit` event yourself and do as you need.